# Why am I blocked from posting questions when connected to a specific network?

Tags: support, banning

I wouldn't have posted this post, but I'm getting blocked from posting questions 2-3 times a day and it's very annoying.

Can a moderator step in and tell me the reason?

If you look at my questions (such as this [Redis int representation of a string is bigger when the string is more than 7 bytes but smaller otherwise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24078598/redis-int-representation-of-a-string-is-bigger-when-the-string-is-more-than-7-by)) you'll see that I put effort in it and that it'll be probably of help to many people (my questions are mostly about optimization, so you see where I'm going).

Now, I was going to answer a question with a lot of details to which there are very little to none details of the net.

As soon as I press submit this is what I see:

> Your post cannot be submitted at this time due to the volume of spam
>   and abuse originating from your network. We apologize for any
>   inconvenience. See the help center for more.

Seriously, spam? Look at my posts and tell me where's the spam/abuse in them. I'd be glad if you helped me to see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Given the error message shown to you, that's not a question ban. That's just you being on some public network that SO received a lot of abuse from. Use another network, or try on another location, and you should be good to go I guess. It's not stating you are the spammer, it merely states that spam and abuse are **originating from your network**.

Comment: @Bart The most annoying fact is that the ban is intermittent, meaning that after 5 or 15 minutes there is no ban but after another few minutes it's there again. Don't know what's going on here.. Can you suggest a proxy? I've not so much choice as of the location unfortunately.

Comment: No, I can't. If I recall correctly a decent solution is to post solid content from a location where you can do so. With sufficient rep/prove you're a good user, I think the system will stop bothering you at a point. (Though that could use some confirmation from those who know).

Comment: That's what I'm doing as I've no one-liner questions nor ones lacking information and effort. It's difficult to contribute in such an environment. As far as rep goes It's not up to me if I get an upvote or not, though I did as I see now. Hope the system will recognize this.

Comment: Blame those who screwed it up for you. :/

Comment: Basically what Bart said, but here's an official page on it: http://stackoverflow.com/help/abuse-block

Comment: That's what's happening already. Like I said, get enough proven good contributions, and the system will let you in no matter if you are on that network again.

Comment: Ok, I'll look forward to it.

Comment: @user3710273 - votes on Meta are different and don't affect the IP throttling/ban anyway.

Comment: @ChrisF Thank you for the info!

Comment: Probably because your post cannot be submitted at this time due to the volume of spam and abuse originating from your network.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Read the error more carefully:

> Your post cannot be submitted at this time due to the volume of spam and abuse originating from your **network**. We apologize for any inconvenience. See the help center for more.

(Emphasis added).

This is a low-level IP based block to prevent spam and by and large it's effective. However, it does occasionally catch innocent users like yourself.

Do you regularly post from a public network, a university network or a workplace?

In this case the actions of your fellow user on **that network** will affect you.

The only way round this is to either:

1. Find a different network or get a static IP address from your ISP. In this latter case only your contributions will affect you.
2. Post good content. As Bart mentions in his [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258601/why-im-constantly-getting-question-banned-when-im-in-fact-not-leaving-bad-qual#comment37058_258601) if the system recognises you as a valuable user (good rep, low flags against your posts, etc.) then the low level IP block won't affect you.

The reason this ban is intermittent is that you are connecting to Stack Overflow from a number of IP addresses, but only one is spam blocked. If you can identify that network then you should be able to avoid it in future.

Comment: Wikipedia has the same problem with their IP bans.

Comment: Now I fully got the picture of this type of ban. The way I'll be doing is to post non-low-quality content as I'm always doing and hope the system will recognize it. Thanks again!

Comment: Also, I should mention that we get a lot of spam and trolling from Tor, so if you are using that anonymizing service, don't be surprised if you are blocked from posting from time to time.

Comment: But the rep for number 2 must be really big. When I post from my phone I always have to fill some captcha.

Comment: @VladimirF that's not an IP block; that's a different check to prevent robots from IP hopping. When in mobile you are probably getting assigned a different IP address from time to time. Reputation doesn't make you immune from that one.