# Could we get a sidebar that doesn't have all these people whining about question quality and bug closing?

Tags: feature-request, community-bulletin

I don't care if they whine, I just don't want to see their whining in the Community Bulletin portion of every page.

If we can't get that, could we just opt out of the Community Bulletin's altogether?

Comment: ... userscript time?

Comment: I wish there was a way for moderators to explicitly mark a question as "this is not important enough to appear in the bulletin; remove it immediately and prevent it from appearing in the future." I, too, have been seeing quite a few things appearing in there that I really wish *wouldn't* appear there, and it's kind of annoying. It's also annoying when things pop up in there that have been completely resolved and have an accepted answer, requiring absolutely no further discussion or visibility. Done deals are done deals.

Comment: Don't tell anyone, @animuson... but [there are a few ways in which moderators can influence that list](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130621/how-are-the-contents-of-the-community-bulletin-determined/130893#130893)...

Comment: @Shog9 I was aware of that, and I thought that only discussions appear there, but I've been seeing some posts tagged with support, bug, and feature-request pop up over there that have never even been tagged with discussion in the history of the question. I'm confused what the actual criteria are. Even now, [this question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258601/why-am-i-blocked-from-posting-questions-when-connected-to-a-specific-network?cb=1) is over there. It's a support question, and I'd say it's not really relevant to our community as a whole.

Comment: See also [Provide a setting to hide Meta posts in the Community Bulletin](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251920/456814).

Comment: I'm sure that everyone would want to see only things they are interested in, in the Community Bulletin, but it would be hard to have few links that everyone will be happy with.

Comment: Ironically I just followed a link to this question whining about whining questions from the community bulletin.

Answer (score 6):

Sorry; I know it's annoying, but... Right now, that's what a lot of folks seem to be preoccupied with. As tiring as it can be to see the same topics rehashed for the umpteenth time, it is critical that folks - like yourself - are aware that there is a forum in which they can make their voices heard.

That said, they say variety is the spice of life and I tend to agree that the bulletin was getting a bit bland. So we've made some changes. For details, see: [Can the threshold for what makes it into the Community Bulletin be raised?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252465/can-the-threshold-for-what-makes-it-into-the-community-bulletin-be-raised)